# Common Substring of two strings

Tags: java, algorithm

This particular interview-question stumped me:

`Given two Strings S1 and S2. Find the longest Substring which is a Prefix of S1 and suffix of S2`.

Through Google, I came across the following solution, but didnt quite understand what it was doing.

```
public String findLongestSubstring(String s1, String s2) {
        List<Integer> occurs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(s2.length()-1)) {
                occurs.add(i);
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(occurs);

        for(int index : occurs) {
            boolean equals = true;
            for(int i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (s1.charAt(index-i) != s2.charAt(s2.length() - i - 1)) {
                    equals = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(equals) {
                return s1.substring(0,index+1);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**My questions:**

1. How does this solution work?

   - And how do you get to discovering this solution?
2. Is there a more intuitive / easier solution?

Comment: *Be the computer*. You have a question that you understand, and a program which answers it, that you don't understand. So the thing to do is to draw up an example on paper and run through the steps one by one. After a while you will either understand what the algorithm is doing, or think of a better one. But it absolutely has to be done practically, with a concrete example, and probably in writing - doing this analysis in your head is harder and takes much more experience with algorithms.

Comment: @KilianFoth I already tried that. Sorry I didnt mention that in the question. The problem I'm facing is that while the solution works, I'm not able to intuitively understand why it works and how did one come to this solution. So was looking for an intuitive explanation of how one would arrive to this solution, or some other solution that is more easily understood by me.

Comment: I implemented a solution in 3 lines of java code [here](https://gist.github.com/ChristianBusch/7065071). As @Kilian wrote you should first try to find a solution on your own, as you will profit way more from it. Even the errors you may make will be of use in the future. ;) The code you posted implemented some optimizations I omitted in my code.

Comment: See my answer for a more in depth description and an explanation for your posted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Part 2 of your question

Here is a shorter variant:

```
public String findLongestPrefixSuffix(String s1, String s2) {

   for( int i = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); ; i--) {
      if(s2.endsWith(s1.substring(0, i))) {
         return s1.substring(0, i);
      }
   }    
}
```

I am using `Math.min` to find the length of the shortest String, as I don't need to and cannot compare more than that.

`someString.substring(x,y)` returns you the String you get when reading someString beginning from character `x` and stopping at character `y`. I go backwards from the biggest possible substring (`s1` or `s2`) to the smallest possible substring, the empty string. This way the first time my condition is true it will be biggest possible substring the fulfills it.

If you prefer you can go the other way round, but you have to introduce a variable saving the length of the longest found substring fulfilling the condition so far:

```
public static String findLongestPrefixSuffix(String s1, String s2) {

   if (s1.equals(s2)) { // this part is optional and will 
      return s1;        // speed things up if s1 is equal to s2
   }                    //

   int max = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
      if (s2.endsWith(s1.substring(0, i))) {
         max = i;
      }
   }
   return s1.substring(0, max);
}
```

For the record: You could start with `i = 1` in the latter example for a tiny bit of extra performance. On top of this you can use `i` to specify how long the suffix has at least to be you want to get. ;) If you writ `Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()) - x` you can use `x` to specify how long the found substring may be at most. Both of these things are possible with the first solution, too, but the min length is a bit more involving. ;)

---

### Part 1 of your question

In the part above the `Collections.reverse` the author of the code searches for all positions in `s1` where the last letter of `s2` is and saves this position.

What follows is essentially what my algorithm does, the difference is, that he doesn't check every substring but only those that end with the last letter of `s2`.

This is some sort of optimization to speed things up. If speed is not that important my naive implementation should suffice. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @TheMorph for such detailed explanation!

Comment: Maybe one should save s1.substring(0, i) in a variable and reuse it instead of calling it twice.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you find that solution? Was it written by a credible, well-respected coder? If you're not sure of that, then it might not be worth reading it. One could write really complex and inefficient code to accomplish something really simple, and it will not be worth understanding the algorithm.

Rather than trying to understand somebody else's solution, it might be easier to come up with it on your own. I think you understand the problem much better that way, and the logic becomes your own. Over time and practice the thought process will start to come more naturally. Practice makes perfect.

Anyway, I put a more simple implementation in Python [here](https://gist.github.com/janosgyerik/7062399) (spoiler alert!). I suggest you first figure out the solution on your own, and compare it to mine later.

Comment: I wrote a [small implementation in java](https://gist.github.com/ChristianBusch/7065071) that is way shorter (total of 3 LOC), and more intuitive imho, then OPs code. On the other hand OPs code has some optimizations missing in ours. Haven't tested it, but my code might be quite slower on large strings, same for your. But I think our codes are good to impart the basic understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Apache commons lang3,  `StringUtils.getCommonPrefix()`

Java is really bad in providing useful stuff via stdlib. On the plus side there's almost always some reasonable tool from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the @TheMorph's answer to javascript. Hope this helps js developer

```
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}

function findLongestPrefixSuffix(s2, s1) {

   for( var i = Math.min(s1.length, s2.length); ; i--) {
      if(s2.endsWith(s1.substring(0, i))) {
         return s1.substring(0, i);
      }
   }    
}

console.log(findLongestPrefixSuffix('abc', 'bcd')); // result: 'bc'
```